# regex code to call the images into a slide (MyBB)

Tags: regex, image, mybb

does anyone here familiar with MyBB?

I want to display all images in a thread in the forums that I have chosen previously in a gallery slide.

[img]*URL_IMAGE_FILE*[/img]

of the slider is a slider that I mean the following.
http://community.mybb.com/attachment.php?aid=26307

that where: 17 and 18 there are IDs that I choose.

```
WHERE t.fid IN (17,18) AND t.visible='1' AND t.closed NOT LIKE 'moved|%' AND t.firstpost=p.pid
```

please correct the following code if there is an error.

```
// Slider Images
/***** Slider Gallery Thread End *****/ 

 /* LATEST THREADS */

$query = $db->query("
       SELECT t.*, p.message, a.aid, a.thumbnail
       FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."threads t
       LEFT JOIN ".TABLE_PREFIX."posts p ON (p.pid = t.firstpost)
       LEFT JOIN ".TABLE_PREFIX."attachments a ON(a.pid=p.pid)
       WHERE t.fid IN (17,18) AND t.visible='1' AND t.closed NOT LIKE 'moved|%' AND t.firstpost=p.pid
       ORDER BY t.dateline DESC
       LIMIT 1");

if(!$db->num_rows($query))

    {
        // Needs to output a nice "no posts here" box
        $title = 'Error';
        $message = 'No Message';

        eval("\$tricks = \"".$templates->get("member_profile_no_content")."\";");

    }
    else

    {
    // Set up the parser options.
    $parser_options = array(
        "allow_html" => $forum['allowhtml'],
        "allow_mycode" => $forum['allowmycode'],
        "allow_smilies" => $forum['allowsmilies'],
        "allow_imgcode" => $forum['allowimgcode'],
        "allow_videocode" => $forum['allowvideocode'],
         "filter_badwords" => 1
        );

    while($threads = $db->fetch_array($query))

        {
        $threads['threadlink'] = get_thread_link($threads['tid']);


        if($threads['lastposteruid'] == 0)

        {
            $lastposterlink = $threads['lastposter'];

        }
        else
        {
            $lastposterlink = build_profile_link($threads['lastposter'], $threads['lastposteruid']);

        }
        $view_string = 'Views';
        $reply_string = 'Replies';
        if($threads['views'] == 1)

        {
            $view_string = 'Views';

        }

        if($threads['replies'] == 1)

        {
            $reply_string = 'Replies';

        }

        if ($thread['thumbnail'])
        {
            $thumbnail = '<a href="'.$mybb->settings['bburl'].'/attachment.php?aid='.$aid.'" target=_blank><img src="./uploads/'.$thread['thumbnail'].'" alt="" title="" width="100%" height="100px"></a>';
        }
        else
        {
            $thumbnail = '';
        }

        $threads['profilelink'] = build_profile_link($threads['username'], $threads['uid']);
        $threads['reply'] = $lang->sprintf($lang->thread_views_stats, my_number_format($threads['replies']), $reply_string, my_number_format($threads['views']), $view_string);
        $threads['date'] = my_date($mybb->settings['dateformat'], $threads['dateline']);
        $threads['time'] = my_date($mybb->settings['timeformat'], $threads['dateline']);
        $threads['lastpostlink'] = get_thread_link($threads['tid'], 0, "lastpost");
        $threads['message'] = my_substr($threads['message'], 0, 150) . "...";
        $threads['message'] = $parser->parse_message($threads['message'], $options);
        eval("\$tricks .= \"".$templates->get("depan_slides")."\";");
    }
        }

/***** Slider Gallery Thread End *****/
```

Comment: @LutzHorn there is no error. but the images files that should be taken from a thread does not show up.

Comment: is not there anything that can help me?